# search function print the next line of my found line! c programming

Tags: c, file, struct, strcmp

I have method add, works good, also I have method view and it's work 
in this method

```
void search(){


 FILE* fr;
fr=fopen("record.txt","r");
Record r;
char na[10];
 printf(" Enter the name:... ");
    scanf("%s",na);

while(fread(&r,sizeof(r),1,fr)){
if(strcmp(na,r.name))
printf(" A match has been found ... ");
printf("%s %s %s \n",r.name,r.email,r.phoneNum);
}
fclose(fr);}`
```

I don't know what's the wrong! 
I have a struct and inside it i have an array of name 
I ask user to enter names, then write it in a file 
if I search for specific name 
the method prints the next name of exact name !

what should I do?

***Record is a struct but I use typedef to rename

Comment: @user3121023 is correct.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strcmp-in-c-cpp/

Comment: **Indentation**!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the `printf("%s %s %s \n",r.name,r.email,r.phoneNum);` within the if brackets so it is going to display each name, not just the matching one.

In addition strcmp will return 0 if it is a match, so currently `printf(" A match has been found ... ");` is executing when a match is not found.